# how to make a menu to pop up when i press settings button on my phone?

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I have an action bar in my activity. + i want simple menu to pop up when i press settings button on my phone. Now onOptionsItemSelected method looks for id in my action bar ? what is wrong in my code ??

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity{


    private ListView MenuList;

    String classes[] = {"NewReviewActivity" };
    public void onCreate(Bundle menuinstance){
        super.onCreate(menuinstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        MenuHelper menu_data[] = new MenuHelper[] {
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_1, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_1)),
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_2, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_2)),
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_3, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_3)),
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_4, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_4)),
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_5, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_5)),
                new MenuHelper(R.drawable.ic_menu_6, this.getString(R.string.menuItemTitle_6))
        };

        final MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_row, menu_data);


        MenuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuListView);
        MenuList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);


        MenuList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                String classchosen = classes[position];
                Class ourClass;
                try {
                    ourClass = Class.forName("com.project.simplify." + classchosen);
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ourClass);
                      startActivity(ourIntent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.print("Class not found");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;

    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Logout:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

layout/menu_row :

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button_bg">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/menuItemIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/menuItemDesc"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menuItemTitle" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

action_bar :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_bar_menu"
          android:title="@string/actionBarMenuTitle"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

and main.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"

    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
>
<item
        android:id="@+id/Report"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/reportTitle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_1"/>
<item
        android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/aboutUsTitle"/>
<item
        android:id="@+id/Logout"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/logoutTitle"/>
</GridView>
</menu>
```